# Showing INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server once hadoop is upgraded to cdh5.2.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Upgraded my Hadoop cluster (CDH) to cdh5.2.0

But once I run my Job with  iteration, It is showing after 1 st iterative Job.

```
14/11/17 09:29:44 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
14/11/17 09:29:45 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
14/11/17 09:29:46 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

​I have some calculations in Driver class. It is working fine for small dataset. When I tried to run 1gb data it is showing above error.

It seems like after my first job some calculation is done in driver class and after the calculation the next job get starts. But I think it is not waiting for the time spend for calculation in driver class(as it is 1 gb file it takes long time for driver calculation, but it is waiting for small files as calculations are less) and throwing the above error.

​It worked fine in previous version.

Whether I missed anything during installation,anything like reporting time or sleep...?

Why is it so? 
Pleace Advice​

Comment: Do you use HA namenode?

Comment: check datanode is connecting with namenode and also check hdfs-site configuration again.